# Check if textbox goes empty after having a value without submitting form or pressing outside of the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a currency exchange in my backend, I post data from my textbox to the currency exchange using ajax and view the exchanged value in a label, which is otherwise hidden.

The problem is, if I enter a value in the textbox, and then erase the value from the textbox, the latest value is still there ( I want to hide the label again when the textbox is empty )

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
    $('#transferAmount').on('change',function () {
    var amount = $('#transferAmount').val();

    if (amount.length < 1 || amount === ""){
    $('#amountExchangedHidden').hide();
}
```

});

I've tried with "on-input" aswell, but it didn't work. Does anyone have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` event instead of `change` event as `change` event handler will only be invoked once `focus` in the `input` field is lost.

> The DOM [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.

```js
$('#transferAmount').on('input', function() {
  var amount = $(this).val();
  $('#amountExchangedHidden').toggle(!!amount.length);
}).trigger('input'); //`.trigger` to invoke the handler initially
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='transferAmount'>
<input type="text" id='amountExchangedHidden'>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I forgot to use ".trigger('input'); " last time i tried on.input :)

Comment: @Coderap, I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

**Use blur Event instead of Change**

```
    $(function)  {
              $('#transferAmount').on('blur',function () {
                    var amount = $('#transferAmount').val();

                      if (amount.length < 1 || amount === ""){
                      $('#amountExchangedHidden').hide();}

             });
});
```

Comment: This was not what I was looking for, blur is when you leave the textbox, I wanted it to change exactly when the textbox becomes empty, even if you erase a value you entered.